# How do I lookup an amount closes to the given value

Tags: excel, vba

Given a decimal number, is there a way to lookup the value in a column that comes closes to amounts array?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use simple array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

```
=INDEX($B2:$B6,MATCH(MIN(ABS($A2:$A6-$D$2)),ABS($A2:$A6-$D$2),0))
```